# Not getting OpenNTF project: Bootstrap for XPages to work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, lotus-domino

Running on IBM Domino R9.0 Social Edition

Installed in the client, verified that the files exists at the proper location.
Installed on the server, same here.

If I do: `tell http osgi ss org.openntf.bootstrap` it says Resolved

Under XSP properties I have both the Extension library and Bootstrap checked.

All this in an otherwise empty database.
Set the theme manually (because it doesn't exist in the dropdown) to `bootstrapv2.3.1`
Create an empty XPage, Clean and build all.

If I open the XPage in a web browser the end result is:

`"The application /test.nsf requires org.openntf.xsp.bootstrap.library. This library cannot be found."`

What am I missing?

Thanks!

/J

Answer (score 2):

Do you by any chance use "local preview"? In this case you need to copy the feature and plugin to the data/domino/workspace/application folder -> that's the one the preview is using

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm using the Domino server. Good tip though!

Answer (score 2):

Never tried the "install" way (copying the files into the relevant dirs). I'm using all of the extensions from an updatesite DB and the OSGI_HTTP_DYNAMIC_BUNDLES setting in the server's notes.ini. Give this a try.
A detailed howto can be found here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_Deployment

Of course this article deals with the deployment of the ExtLib itself but you can use the updatesite for any other extension, too - such as the Bootstrap Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Bootstrap extension library on a Domino test server. I had to restart the server as simply stopping and starting http didn't work for me.

Comment: Both the server and machine have been restarted, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

What functions are you trying to test? Are you trying to use the application layout?
Try this and let me know if it works for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout2">
    <xe:this.facets>
        <xp:callback xp:key="LeftColumn" facetName="LeftColumn"
            id="callback1">
        </xp:callback>
        <xp:callback xp:key="RightColumn" facetName="RightColumn"
            id="callback2">
        </xp:callback>
    </xe:this.facets>

    <xp:callback id="OneUIMainAreaCallback"></xp:callback>
    <xe:this.configuration>
        <xe:applicationConfiguration placeBarName="test"
            productLogoHeight="60">


            <xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
                <xe:loginTreeNode enabled="true" loaded="true"
                    rendered="true">
                </xe:loginTreeNode>
            </xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>

        </xe:applicationConfiguration>
    </xe:this.configuration>
</xe:applicationLayout></xp:view>
```

Now drop that thing on an xPages, give it the bootstrapv2.3.1r theme and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to setup the bootstrap library on my server using the updatesite-runtime.nsf downloaded from openntf.org.

I had forgotten to sign the plugins (Action/Sign all), which stopped the bundles loading correctly.

I know this isn't answering your question, I just wanted to post it here for future searches as this question was one of the most helpful.